# Vbscript classic asp custom classes

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

Is it possible to create customer classes in classic asp (vbscript) like you can in asp.net with c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently it is.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ah5852c%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) And [here is an ASP 101 article](http://www.asp101.com/articles/richard/ooasp/default.asp) on using them with ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use a class file . All you need to do is write your function on a file. Suppose the name of your file is func.asp . Write all your functions or procedures in the file "func.asp" and use it
  `<!-- #include file ="subs_functions.asp" -->` 
Write the above line in all the pages where you want to use the functions written on "func.asp page.
If your class file is in the server(root folder) the code will be something like

```
<!-- #include virtual ="\YourFolderNames\myfilename.asp" -->
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with classes. It is an include file that contains (something), in your example maybe a list of functions or subroutines (neither of which are classes).

Comment: Right you are @Gary. It was back in 2012.

Comment: Correct, but I wanted to be sure that anyone coming across this post, as I recently did, knew the answer was incorrect (even back in 2012). Just for clarity.